Instagram API with Facebook login : /me/accounts does not list all pages , does not list instagram account details even after linking it to a fb page
My app is registered on facebook and has been live since the past 2 years. Now, i switched it to development mode since i need to integrate with "Instagram API with Facebook login".
So after following the documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-facebook-login/business-login-for-instagram , i linked my insta business account to one of my facebook pages using this link https://www.facebook.com/business/help/connect-instagram-to-page (Note : My facebook account has 2 pages)
I also linked the fb account to insta account by following this : https://help.instagram.com/176235449218188
I have added instagram under products section in my registered app in facebook. I have not confgured anything with respect to "API Setup with facebook login" there.
Now, iam trying to access /me/accounts to get all the pages data and instagram business account id by including scopes "instagram_basic" and "instagram_content_publish"
But iam not getting any data in graph API tool. It just returns
{
  "data": [
  ]
}

I have tried to debug, but couldnt figure it out. Iam stuck at this point. Any help would be appreciated,thanks.

From the previous Get started page: "Set up your implementation to request these permissions: instagram_basic pages_show_list"

@C3roe I am using their Graph API explorer. And since my app is in Development mode, i have already included these permissions when i request for pages data. But still, i get empty data.

Try and remove all permissions, and then add them again. Does the auth dialog ask you for permission to access your pages then? Does it show a list of pages, asking you to select which ones you want to grant access to?

@C3roe Yes it does, the dialog shows the permissions requested, the list of facebook pages selected and the list of instagram accounts selected. Only then the access token is generated.
